# I am a toy, but which one?

Tags: riddle

I'm a puppet with no strings
And a modern lover might wear my namesake with her interstellar apparel
I tell you that I *do* wanna know
What you would call me no matter your altitude
I'm not the kind that goes up to your knees
Almost everyone has wanted me to be theirs
R U ready to guess?

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lines seem to all be references to

> Their songs (Do I wanna know, R U Mine, etc)

I'm a puppet with no strings

> "I'm a puppet on a string" - R U Mine

And a modern lover might wear my namesake with her interstellar apparel

> "Arabella's got some interstellar-gator skin boots", "But she's a modern lover" - Arabella

I tell you that I do wanna know

> Do I wanna know

What you would call me no matter your altitude

> Why'd you only call me when your high?

I'm not the kind that goes up to your knees

> Knee Socks

Almost everyone has wanted me to be theirs

> I wanna be yours

R U ready to guess?

> R U Mine - I sure hope so!

Answer:

> Sock Monkey - type of monkey (like arctic monkeys), wear them with their nightgown, This sock doesn't go to their knees, sock puppets have no strings

Comment: I explicitly stated that I am a toy, also only two of the lines are R U mine but that doesn't matter so much

Comment: @kanoo just noticed that! updated with that piece :)

Comment: Still no, sorry

Comment: @kanoo Is there anything I'm missing? It fits all the lines and the theme?

Comment: Yeah, there is, I'm not giving away hints so soon after posting the riddle but it seems that you haven't read it so much as noticed what defined each of the lines. I tucked clues inside a couple (but not all) of the lines as to which toy I am referring to.

Comment: Tidy it up and name the songs correctly and it's yours